# Spring Annotations Import Config not called

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-annotations

I am trying to make an application that uses Spring annotations to import the configurations. For this question i narrowed it down to two files. The Startup class:

```
package core;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@Import(ConfigSettings.class)
public class Startup {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    log.info("main class");
    }
}
```

and the ConfigSettings
package core;

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"connections", "filter"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:config/${env.config:dev}.application.properties"})
public class ConfigSettings {

    public ConfigSettings() {
    log.info("Constructor ConfigSettings");
    }
}
```

I expected the outcome to be:

```
[INFO]Constructor ConfigSettings
[INFO]main class
```

But it only shows mainclass. It looks like the constructor of the config settings is not called at all. I expect it to call it because of the import annotation.

Can anyone explain what is going wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why.  `@Import` is only relevant in the context/scope of a Spring `ApplicationContext` you are just running a `main` method.

Comment: Your `main` method has nothing to do with Spring container. Therefore you cannot expect it to bootstrap Spring Context and Configuration classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to make the config class return config object that contains your values. Generally I don't tend to add an all-encompassing config object, but have a config file for each component (database, controllers, etc...).

You can then return the configured object as a bean and let spring inject it. If I were to make a config file for a RestTemplate (as a simple example):

```
@Service
public class RestClientConfig {

    @Value("${your.config.value}")
    private String yourValue;


    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      // Configure it, using your imported values
      // ...

      return restTemplate;
   }
}
```

However, the `main` method is outside of the spring container and you won't be able to bootstrap it that way, but with the above method you can call the configured component directly where you need to use it.

Comment: Thanks! I have a hard time understanding what the containers do but i think its starting to make sense now. Just a check if i got this right: The reason it didnt work was because i had my main method outside my Spring container and therefor it couldn't bootstrap it. With a workaround (like this, or the applicationcontext), the components are configured without the need of a main in a Spring container? Is that correct? Thank you for your time!

Comment: "With a workaround (like this, or the applicationcontext), the components are configured without the need of a main in a Spring container?" Close; if you're using Spring it will wrap your application in a spring container, but what this does is utilise classes that are within the application context to do the configuring, that way, spring can see them and will create the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing @Bean

> @Bean
> public ConfigSettings() {